# how can i fix Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : in jsonp

Tags: ajax

my code is

```
   $("#submit").click(function(){

       var inId = $("#inId").val();

       $.ajax({
              url: 'http://boss.abc.com/x/Invoice/' + inId + '/5',
              type: 'GET',
              dataType: 'jsonp',
               jsonpCallback: 'callback',
          success: function (data) {
              console.log(data);
          }
         });
    });
```

It show url like http://boss.abc.com/x/Invoice/333/5?callback=callback&_=1440574382621

Comment: The syntax error is in the returned JSON so you need to post that too.

Comment: how? please explain it clearly

Comment: The AJAX request gets back a JSON string which is attempted to be parsed into a JSON object but the string is not valid JSON. Use http://jsonlint.com to find out what the problem is with the syntax.

Comment: {
    "Invoice": [
        {
            "InId": 5345,
            "LD": 7385430,
            "VrNo": 4543,
            "ITEMID": 345,
            "OUTWARD": 45,
            "INWARD": 45,
            "Vpe": 345
        }
    ]
}     it is my json, and jsonlint.com show it valid json

Comment: This JSON string is valid, should not throw error.

Comment: so why is it showing error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :